# Pycharm error, numpy has no attribute 'loadtext'

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I was initially getting an error downloading scipy from pycharm so I followed the steps found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) where I downloaded numpy+mkl and scipy. I saw that there were both in my project interpreter on pycharm. But now I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/PycharmProjects/MachineLearningHW1/HW1.py", line 7, in <module>
    train_data = np.loadtext('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA 5635/DataSets/arcene/arcene_train.data')
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'loadtext'
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue, here is my entire code for sake of completeness:

```
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np


# Load Data
train_data = np.loadtext('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA 5635/DataSets/arcene/arcene_train.data')
train_labels = np.loadtext('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA 5635/DataSets/arcene/arcene_train.labels')
test_data = np.loadtext('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA 5635/DataSets/arcene/arcene_test.data')
test_labels = np.loadtext('C:/Users/Morgan Weiss/Desktop/STA 5635/DataSets/arcene/arcene_test.labels')

# Error
error_train = []
error_test = []

# Make decision tree
for i in range(1,13):
    DT = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = i)
    DT = DT.fit(train_data,train_labels)
    error_train.append(1 - DT.score(train_data,train_labels))
    error_test.append(1 - DT.score(test_data,test_labels))

# Print out depth, training, and testing error
for i in range(12):
    print(i+1, error_train[i], error_test[i])
```

Comment: Omit the `e` in `txt` - it's called `loadtxt`. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is quite explicit.  `numpy` does not have any function `loadtext`.  You surely intended:

```
np.loadtxt
```

Comment: But I loaded import numpy as np?

Comment: @Wolfy it should be np.loadtxt and not np.loadtext